# Jquery to validate if input exists in particular table column

Tags: jquery

I have a table containing a list of unique values in the second column. There is an input field to add a new row onto the field, but before inserting the row, I want to validate that the particular field value does not already exists in the table.

In my on-click event, I have tried the following:

```
if ($('#tablename tr > td:contains('+VALUE+')').length!=0)
{
    alert("Please enter a unique row number.");
}
```

The problem with this is that it does not limit to a certain column, so if I enter a value that exists in any other cell of the table, it displays the alert.  How can I restrict it to searching for an exact match, and only in the second column.

THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if ($('#tablename tr > td:nth-child(2):contains(' + VALUE + ')').length != 0) {
    alert("Please enter a unique row number.");
}
```

it may not be proper because of a row contains `abc` and then you try to add `ad` it won't allow, so try

```
var $tds = $('#tablename tr > td:nth-child(2)').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == VALUE;
});
if ($tds.length != 0) {
    alert("Please enter a unique row number.");
}
```

Comment: I was just typing up your second demo. Heads up though, you forgot `return` in `filter()`.

Comment: Your second piece of code worked great. Thanks for the prompt reply!